# how to input username by getting the half of the first name and half of the last name and the day of the given birthday

Tags: java, string, integer, passwords

[example of output should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wLmc.png)

please help thank you in advance!!

the output of the code in username should be the 2 letter in firt name and 3 in last name and date number

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Enter Fullname:");
    String fullname = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Birthday : ");
    String bday = sc.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Your Login Details");
    System.out.println("Enter Fullname:" + fullname);
    
    System.out.println("Enter Birthday : " + bday);
    System.out.println("Enter Username: " + );
    
    

    
    
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input will always be in the format you provided, you can use [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) and [`String.substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) to extract the required information from the input as shown below.

```
String[] splitName = fullName.split(" ");
String firstName = splitName[0];
String lastName = splitName[1];
String day = bday.split("-")[1];

String username = firstName.substring(0, 2) + lastName.substring(0, 3) + day;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to achieve the expected result. The name should always be in this format FirstName LastName, otherwise, you may encounter NullPointerException more frequently. There are split and substring methods in the string class. Follow these steps to get started

1. Full name should be split into two strings, the first is for the first name and another is for the last name, for this we will use the split method which returns String[].
2. After splitting the full name, the substring method comes into the picture, substring method takes two parameters first and the last index. We can use this method with both strings received by the split method.

`String[] firstLastName = fullname.split(" ");`

`System.out.println("Enter Username: " + firstLastName[0].substring(0, 2) + firstLastName[1].substring(0, 3) + bday.split("-")[1]);`

Syntax

1. `Public String [] split ( String regex, int limit)`
2. `public String substring(int begIndex, int endIndex)`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.